# Hei , im newbie and can't see what is wrong here , and or its safe contract what i writing

Tags: contract-development

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;

contract Token {

  mapping(address => uint) public balances;
  mapping(address =>mapping(address =>uint)) public allowance;
  uint public totalSupply = 100000000000000 * 10 ** 18;
  string public name = "RoboDog";
  string public symbol = "RoboDog";
  uint public decimals = 18;

  event transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);
  event approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);

 constructor()  {
  balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
 }

 function balance0f(address owner) public view returns(uint) {
  return balances [owner];
 }

 function tranfer(address to, uint value) public returns(bool) {
  require(balance0f(msg.sender) >= value , 'balance to low');
  balances[to] += value;
  balances[msg.sender] -= value;
  emit transfer(msg.sender, to, value);
  return true;
 }

  function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value) public returns(bool) {
   require(balance0f)(from) >= value; 'balance to low';(bool) 
   require(allowance)[from][msg.sender] >= value; 'allowance to low';
   balances[to] += value;
   balances[from] -= value;
   emit tranfer(from, to, value);
   return true;
 }

 function approve(address spender, uint value) public returns(bool) {
  allowance[msg.sender][spender] = value;
  emit approval(msg.sender, spender, value);
  return true;
 }
}
```

Comment: What is the question ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out for unnecessary space between balances and[owner]

```
return balances [owner]
```

Wrong use of brackets

```
require(balance0f(msg.sender) >= value , 'balance to low'); // balance0f[msg.sender]  needs to be    

require(balance0f)(from) >= value; 'balance to low';(bool) // (balance0f[from] >= value, 'balance too low') needs to be, and (bool) is escaped from you i guess.

require(allowance)[from][msg.sender] >= value; 'allowance to low'; // require(allowance[from][msg.sender] >= value)
```